# integration with two variables and limits calculation

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How do you proceed for the following? I know I have to treat y as a constant to integrate but I am stuck on how to do it. I tried by parts without success I am sure there is a trick to it?

$\underset{y \mapsto 1 ^{-}}{lim}\int_{ln{y}}^{0} (\frac{xln(e^{x}-x+x^{2})}{(y-1)^{3}})dx$

Comment: The l'Hôpital's rule can work.

Comment: I can't compute the integral. I am not suppose to do that before using hospital to find the limit?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{y\to 1^-}\int_{\ln{y}}^{0}\frac{x\ln(e^{x}-x+x^{2})}{(y-1)^{3}}dx=$$

$$=\lim_{y\to 1^-}\dfrac{\int_{\ln{y}}^{0}x\ln(e^{x}-x+x^{2})}{(y-1)^{3}}dx$$

Being a limit of the type $0/0$ (as the integral vanishes if $y=1$ because $\ln y=0$), we can apply the l'Hôpital's rule. For the derivative of the integral, we have to use the Leibniz rule:

$$L=\lim_{y\to 1^-}\dfrac{-\ln y\ln(y-\ln y+\ln^2y)/y}{3(y-1)^2}$$

Again a $0/0$ type. It's easy to follow from here using l'Hôpital again, maybe twice.

Comment: how are you sure the integral vanishes if ln(y)=0 ?

Comment: Because there is no singularity in the integrand at $x=0$ and the integral vanishes when the limits are the same: inferior limit $\ln 1=0$ and superior $0$ too.